# MPI_Gatherv vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi

Hello everyone i'm pretty new to MPI and i found out searching on the site that there is a way to collect dynamically sized vector with the combination of gather for the size and then gatherv.
However i have a problem with my code which is a test i'm running to see if i'm doing it correctly.

```
int main(int arg, char** argvs) {
MPI_Init(&arg, &argvs);
int size, rank;
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

vector<int> vectordata;
if (rank == 1)
    vectordata.push_back(2);
if (rank == 2) {
    vectordata.push_back(1);
    vectordata.push_back(5);
}

int *counts = new int[size];
int nelements = (int)vectordata.size();
// Each process tells the root how many elements it holds
MPI_Gather(&nelements, 1, MPI_INT, counts, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// Displacements in the receive buffer for MPI_GATHERV
int *disps = new int[size];
// Displacement for the first chunk of data - 0
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    disps[i] = (i > 0) ? (disps[i - 1] + counts[i - 1]) : 0;

// Place to hold the gathered data
// Allocate at root only
vector<int> alldata;
if (rank == 0)
    // disps[size-1]+counts[size-1] == total number of elements
    alldata = vector<int>(disps[size - 1] + counts[size - 1]);
// Collect everything into the root
MPI_Gatherv(vectordata.data(), nelements, MPI_INT,
    alldata.data(), counts, disps, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

cout << alldata.size() << endl;
cout << alldata[0] << endl;
cout << alldata[1] << endl;
cout << alldata.back() << endl;

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

the first cout should print 3, instead it prints:
0
0
3
the last 3 cout print:
2
1
5

however after printing it crashes saying: Debug assertion Failed! vector subscript out of range.
I think it has something to do with the displacement but i'm not sure what and it would be wonderful if somebody could explain me the line where i calculate disps[i] since i got it from a previous answer and i don't fully understand it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Gatherv` gathers everything to the master rank. `alldata` on all ranks not equal to the master rank is still empty (hence the two `0`s initially, as well as the "Debug assertion Failed!" error). Put the set of `cout`s in a `if (rank == 0)` block, or make sure to broadcast all of the data to the other ranks before you do your `cout`.